# Container Interface - Detailed Explanation

Tags: c#, oop

I was just reading up a lecture which breifly went over Container Interface.
I didn't fully comprehend the material and couldn't find too much via google. What I was wondering was, can any of you explain it in real world terms. Also explaining alternatives and when its better to use which? If that is the case.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about IContainer in System.ComponentModel. Basically, this is an interface that defines what behaviour is expected of a component container. This allows you to create different containers, that the ComponentCollection can work with.

Note that IContainer doesn't necessarily have to contain visual components - it is perfectly valid for the components to be data only.